# Поиск с помощью LIKE без учета символов MySQL

Tags: mysql, поиск

Нужно организовать поиск по полю без учета символов препинания, кавычек и других подобных символов. Например, в БД хранится запись: `ОАО "Мега - Компания"`, а при поиске вводят: `ОАО Мега Компания`. Данный запрос должен вывести `ОАО "Мега - Компания"`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли стандартными средствами организовать такой поиск или необходимо писать функцию для MySQL?

Comment: можете попробовать regexp http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Pattern_matching.html только там бывают чудеса с русскими буквами

Comment: %ОАО%Мега%Компания% Вот так должно искать.

Comment: получается, каждый пробел нужно заменить знаком **%**? А не сильно это скажется на производительности БД? Поиск осуществляется по полям varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Символ `%` соответствует любому количеству символов (даже 0):

```
SELECT * LIKE 'ОАО%Мега%Компания%';
```

Символ `_` соответствует ровно одному символу:

```
SELECT * LIKE 'ОАО _Мега _ Компания_';
```

Answer (score 0):

более правильнее будет организовать поиск так

```sql
select name from tbl where name like '%Мега%' and name '%ком%'
```

на скорости отбора это не будет слишком сказываться. для увеличения скорости  - используй 5.7.хх, производил замеры 10 000 000 записей поиск по всем (в условиях поиска заранее не присутствующие наборы) - 4,5сек. при наличии введённого - время очень маленькое, практичесаяи вероятность того, что у тебя будет такое количество названий фирм мало, следовательно поиск "мнгновенный". Реально работающее приложение - такой поиск , mysql 5.5.xx - поиск в 28 000 записей - тормозов не наблюдается. (ввод посимвольный на странице браузера, отправка на сервер по ws, возврат результатов). Таких **and name '%ком%** можно добавлять множество, но практика показывает, что конечный результат локализуется в 2-3 записи уже при 3 .
Преимущество такого - можно вводить в любом порядке